# How to get a foundation Reveal Modal to display properly in Safari

Tags: html, css, safari, modal-dialog, zurb-foundation-5

The Foundation Reveal Modal works fine in Chrome, Firefox and IE; but not Safari.

When I click the login link the modal only halfway appears on the screen.  In all other browsers it remains centered on the screen.

You can see a [video of my test on Safari 6.2](http://app.crossbrowsertesting.com/public/i38395d7d64cef6c/livetests/3521993/videos/z51af3159285b5601b16).

I tried the suggestions on the [Foundation Forum](http://foundation.zurb.com/forum/posts/10675-reveal-modal-just-slides-off-page-in-safari), but they didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a simple solution.

CSS

`.left-50p { left: 50%; }`

HTML

`<div id="signupModal" class="reveal-modal left-50p" data-reveal>`